# jQuery display button if all selects have a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of select options that a client can use to change product options to suit their needs. This will change the price, which works. However the bit I can't get working is that I want the buy button hidden until at least one option from each select is selected.

At the moment it works, however the buy button is revealed if just one of the options has a selection. How can I make sure it only appears if ALL the selects have an option selected?

I've little control over HTML, so working with what I have

HTML:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product__price">
      £20.00
    </div>

    <div id="final_item_price" class="item_price hidden">20.00</div>

    <div class="product__options">
      <h3>Colour</h3>
      <select name="product option 1" id="select1" class="cartDdlOptions">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="5.0000~U">Blue</option>
        <option value="5.0000~U">Orange</option>
      </select>

      <h3>Size</h3>
      <select name="product option 2" id="select2" class="cartDdlOptions">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="5.0000~U">Small</option>
        <option value="5.0000~U">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="buy__btn">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var optionsTotal = null,
  itemPrice = parseFloat($(".item_price").text());

      $(".cartDdlOptions").on('change', function() {

          optionsTotal = new Number(0);
          $.map($(".cartDdlOptions").find('option:selected'), function (el, i) {
              var v = new Number( $(el).val(function(i, v){return v.replace("~U","");}).val());
              optionsTotal += v;
          });

          $(".product__price").html('&pound;' + (optionsTotal + itemPrice).toFixed(2));

      }).change();

      $(".product__price").html('&pound;' + (optionsTotal + itemPrice).toFixed(2));

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //start of second part that doesn't work
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(".buy__btn").hide();

    var thisvalue = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

      $(".cartDdlOptions").change(function() {

        if ($(thisvalue) == ""){
            $(".detailProductBuyButton").hide();
        }

        else{      
           $(".buy__btn").show();
        }
    });

  });
```

**Working example:** http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/nxqts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that :

```
var $select = $(".product__options select"); //Cache the select

$select.on('change', function() {
    var valid = true; //Flag
    $select.each(function() {
        return valid = !!this.value //Assign the flag a bolean is valid or not
    });

    $(".buy__btn").toggle(valid); //Display/hide
});
```

Comment: Karl, If i wanted to tie in something else to be visible or hidden on the toggle of the buy btn, how would I do that? Basically i have something i need to hide when the buy btn is visible

Comment: @Mat-visual `$('the thing you want to hide').toggle(!valid)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at this:

```
var $options = $(".product_options select");

$options.on('change', function() {
  var selectedCount = 0;
  $options.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      selectedCount ++;
    }
  });

  // All select fields have been selected.
  if (selectedCount === $options.length) {
    $(".buy__btn").show();
  } else {
    $(".buy__btn").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Appreciated the help!